# gnome flashback 18.04

Tags: gnome-flashback

I just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04. Gnome flashback is still an option at the login screen, but when I login, it seems that the new flashback is to gnome 3. Is there no flashback that still looks and works like gnome 2? Isn't someone keeping packages in some repository?

Comment: Try installing the `gnome-session-flashback` and if that doesn't work, try reinstalling it `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-session-flashback`

Comment: Installation of GNOME Panel package may help too. Install it with `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`.

Comment: I had tried unsinstalling completely (using synaptic) and reinstalling, to no avail. I eventually did a clean install of 18.04, us9ing the existing file structure on the drives, and keeping the old /home. Interestingly, this process, includiong installing the special tools I use (grace, kbibtex, lyx, gfortran, etc.) seemd to take less time than the upgrade. I do have a pretty fast internet connection, and, maybe more importantly, I have a solid state drive for the system. Anyway,  I have a gnome 2 look and feel again, happily. Incidentally, if you miss gnome-search-tool, you can get it back.